# Выполнение фоновой задачи по нажатию на уведомление android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notification

Мне нужно, чтобы впн туннель выключался при нажатии на уведомление.
Я нашел такой код, но не понимаю где писать код, выполняющий, собственно, действие. Если писать в notify_intent, он выполняется сразу, а не при нажатии на уведомление.

```
var notify_intent = Intent(requireContext(),  HomeFragment::class.java).apply {
    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    setFlags(flags)

}


val pendingIntent: PendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(
        requireContext(),
        0,
        notify_intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
    )
```

UPD

Дошел до такого решения, но оно все равно не работает

```
var notify_intent = Intent(requireContext(),  NotifyReceiver::class.java)
val pendingIntent: PendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                requireContext(),
                0,
                notify_intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )
```

NotifyReceiver:

```
class NotifyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Log.e("TEST", intent.action!!)
        val it = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)
        context.sendBroadcast(it)
    }

}
```

Comment: Интент это посылка с сообщением. Тот кто ее получит, откроет, прочтет и выполнит. Там у получателя и код писать надо.

Answer (score 0):

Объявление в манифесте решило мою проблему.

```
<receiver android:name=".NotifyReceiver"/>
```